# Why is this not returning true?

Tags: java, methods, slick2d

```
public void check() {
    if (particle < 0) {
        if (point[3].equals(point[3]) == true) {
            check = true;
        }
        check = false;
    }
}
```

Shouldn't `point[3]` be equal to itself? making it true?

Comment: try: `check = (p3.equals(p3));` saves you some if's!

Comment: don't do `if (condition == true)`. it is the same as `if (condition)`!

Comment: @RudolfMühlbauer believe it or not but some people consider `if( method() == true ) /* blah blah */` a *good software engineering practice* to indicate the return type of `method()`. While I strongly disagree, I've seen it as part of a coding standard for a project. Yes, a Java project :/

Comment: @Tom, everything is possible! I had quite some discussion with my professor about this topic - now i believe it should be `if (cond)`.

Answer (score 2):

You must return after `check = true;` from the function, or use `else`. Else it will fall down from the if and `return false` always

```
if (...) {
  check = true;
}
else {
  check = false;
}

public void check(){
    if(particle < 0){
        if(point[3].equals(point[3]) == true){
            check = true;
        }else{
          check = false;
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: What? sorry, I'm only starting :L

Comment: I believe an `else` would be more readable here than a return. And `check = p3.equals(p3);` would be even better yet. As long as we consider a condition like that worth checking anyway.

Comment: @user1610541 what's happening in your code is, it first checks if particle is less than 0, then it checks if point[3].equals(point[3]). If yes, check becomes equal to true. THEN immediately after that, check becomes equal to false, because even if it was logically correct, there was a side-effect phenomena here, which changed the value of check to false. This is why it returned false always. When you return from the function OR use an else{} statement, the logic change of "check" becomes true and is returned from the check() function.

Comment: @user1610541 my wild guess is, you were once a VB programmer.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you mean to say else check = false?

```
   public void check(){
     if(particle < 0){
        if(point[3].equals(point[3]) == true){
         check = true;
        }else{
          check = false;
        }
     }
  //here it is true
  }
```

or simply:

```
  public void check(){
     if(particle < 0){
        check = point[3].equals(point[3]);
     }
     //here it is true
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public boolean check() {
    if (particle < 0) {
        return point[3].equals(point[3]);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: result is not the same as in the question: return value is changed, and the variable `check` is only set when `particle >= 0` in the original code.

Answer (score 0):

what about particle?

by convention point ought to be equal to itself, but you could always implement it otherwise.

but of course, the other reply is correct, this function will always end with check=false